# Increment varchar values on duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, varchar

I know that varchar type of columns are not incrementable, but I want to do something like this:

When a duplicated value is inserted, the new one will be tagged with a number at the end.

For example, we have post-name on our column in the database. Another value post-name is entered, so the next is going to be `post-name-2`, followed by `post-name-3`.

I have programmed something in php but its not very convenient.

```
        $post_url_ = $post_url." %";
        $stmt_check1 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_url LIKE :post_url ");
        $stmt_check2 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_url = :post_url ");

        $stmt_check1->bindparam(":post_url",$post_url_);
        $stmt_check2->bindparam(":post_url",$post_url);

        $stmt_check1->execute();
        $stmt_check2->execute();

        $rows1 = $stmt_check1->rowCount();
        $rows2 = $stmt_check2->rowCount();

        if($rows1<=0 && $rows2==1) {
        $repeat_no = $rows1+1; 
        $post_url = $post_url."-$repeat_no";
        }
        if($rows1>0){
        $repeat_no = $rows1+1; 
        $post_url = $post_url."-$repeat_no";


        }
```

Comment: In db level I think is better you create a separated field for that. other wise you cant compare `post-1` with `post-2`, and if you need do some concatention for the UI, do it on the `SELECT`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza so there is no way i can set this up on db level ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza after thinking a little more , what you suggest is i create another field like : duplicated_version . And this field is going to hold the number of that particular url as many times as it is entered after it was created. Like a counter , thank you this solves it best.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza please add your suggestion as an answer so i can accept it :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to create a complicate process to keep the correct name, just add separated field `version`

Then for UI proporse just concatenate both

```
 SELECT CONCAT(post , '-', version)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use do...while loop to check next numbers. It isn't performance problem, becuase you will use that only on save new record.

1. Before loop, create counter (initial by 0).
2. In loop - if counter > 0, add number to end of url
3. Increase counter
4. Check if url exists in database (while results from db > 0)

Comment: i understand you , i was hoping to find something more in db level , but i guess there is no way to do it.